# user warning: INSERT command denied to user

Tags: 6, database

I am not able to insert rows into a table even though I have granted permissions to the corresponding database user.

I am able to insert rows into the same table with the same user from an individual php application. But if I try to insert a row from drupal, I get the error message as follows.

```
user warning: INSERT command denied to user 'username'@'localhost' for table 'table_name'
```

I even tried changing the password of the database user and changed the settings.php of drupal to reflect the new password, but still I get the same error message. I am able to run the `SELECT` queries successfully but not `INSERT` queries. What might be the problem here? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What code do you use to insert your row ? There [is a very special way](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database.inc/group/database/6) to do this under Drupal, and it is highly recommended to use it.

Comment: I am using this to insert. `$query = "INSERT INTO db.table(col1,col2,col3) VALUES ('%d','%s','%d')";
db_query($query,1,'dfgdsfgs',1);`

Comment: Maybe your alias is what screws you. Try `$query = "INSERT INTO {table} (col1,col2,col3) VALUES ('%d','%s','%d')";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't really make sense. Drupal is just a PHP application; if you're using **exactly** the same connection details in Drupal as you are in your stand-alone PHP application, and that works, it's only logical that your Drupal connection will work too.

You've obviously checked that the username and password are correct, but have you checked the Drupal is connecting to the server from `localhost`? That would be the only other possible difference. If Drupal is connecting from a remote machine then you'll need to grant specific privileges to the user for that specific location.

The easiest way to see what you've already got is to run a `SHOW GRANTS` query on the database in question. That will show you something like this:

```
Grants for username@localhost
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, SHUTDOWN, PROCESS, FILE, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, SUPER, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER ON *.* TO 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

Plus a few more more rows more than likely.

Check through those rows to make doubly sure that there is a grant for `INSERT` for the database user AND the location that the Drupal website is connecting from.

**EDIT**

You could maybe get around the error using `drupal_write_record()`:

```
$record = new stdClass;
$record->col1 = 'something';
$record->col2 = 'something';
$record->col3 = 'something';

drupal_write_record('table_name', $record);
```

But that really *shouldn't* make any difference

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I ran the `SHOW GRANTS` query and I found an entry for `SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE` on particular table for the user. I do not have that entry as `user@localhost` but as `user@%` which I guess is applicable for accessing from remote location also.

Comment: Yeah the wildcard should make it match ok. It's very weird, Drupal itself writes to the database at various points so you should be seeing errors all over the place if the db user doesn't have INSERT privileges. It shouldn't make any difference but have you tried `drupal_write_record` instead? I'll put an example in the answer just in case you haven't

Comment: Even `drupal_write_record` fails. I have two databases setup and this table is from the second database and not the drupal database. So I am not getting errors at various points.

Comment: Ahhhh that's your problem then :) Have a look at [How to connect to multiple databases within Drupal](http://drupal.org/node/18429), it has all the info you'll need

Comment: I know how to have multiple database connections. I am using the two databases for the whole project. But I am not able to access this table alone because of permission errors. I just found that I get different privileges for `'user'@'localhost'` and `'user'@'%'`. So I think they both are used in different scenarios. What do you think?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest...I'd try temporarily granting the same permissions that `'user'@'localhost'` has to `'user'@'%'` to see if you can at least narrow down the problem to that

Comment: The problem is solved now. I granted the same permission to both `'user'@'localhost'` and `'user'@'%'` and it worked. Thanks to you.